# how to make free variable check function in ocaml lambda

Tags: ocaml

I want to make free variable checking function in lambda.

```
lambda experience is 
type exp =
Var of var
| Lambda of var * exp
| App of exp * exp
and var = string
```

In checking function, if free variable is included, then return false, else true.

For example, `Lambda ("x", Var "x")` is true, `Lambda ("y", Var "x")` is false.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783338/free-variables-list-of-a-lambda-expression?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free variables list of a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783338/free-variables-list-of-a-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 1):

The task seems to be a homework assignment, so it is unlikely to get solution-answers.

A couple of hints:

- think of what type should your function have
- your function needs to pattern match on `exp`, so think of how to handle each variant, i.e. Lambda, App, Var.
- think of definition of a free variable to help you with handling cases in the hint above

You could also address Benjamin Pierce's book Types and Programming Languages on further reading on this topic.